# condition variable when the condition function called?

Tags: c++, multithreading

```
template <typename T>
class BlockingQueue{
private:
    queue<T> _queue;
    mutex _mutex;
    condition_variable _cond;
public:
    void push( const T& item){
        unique_lock<mutex> locker(_mutex);
        _queue.push(item);
        locker.unlock();
        _cond.notify_one();
    }
    T pop(){
        unique_lock<mutex> locker(_mutex);
        _cond.wait(locker, [=](){ return !_queue.empty() ;} ); //lambda function, capture by value
        T item = _queue.front();
        _queue.pop();
        return item;
    }
};
```

So this is a blockingqueue implementation. I have 2 questions

1. in push function, lock.unlock() before _cond notify_one(); is this necessary, because when function returns the locker is out of scope and release the mutex. Does it has to be before notify?
2. why the condition lambda function in pop() is passed by value?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the second question, but the first is No, it isn't necessary. If there is an active waiter on the condvar it will receive the notification but not exit the wait until the mutex is available. Generally if possible you want to do your push like you have it now, as it produces less contention on the mutex, but is more prone to potentially spurious wake ups with more than a single waiter.

Comment: I think the lambda is capturing `this` rather than `_queue`. Since `this` is a pointer capture by value Is appropriate.

Comment: @AlanStokes I believe you're correct. I'm used to doing it with `[this]`, but I can certainly see how you describe it as being accurate. I believe `[=]` implicitly capture's `this`.

Comment: Suggestion: Keep the `_cond.notify_one()` call under the lock, wake/wait races are a pain.

Comment: @Hasturkun: this is a misconception: the mutex is about the condition (queue.empty()).  There is no extra race condition when signalling without mutex (as I found out in a similar discussion). see also: http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html